# Using one attribute of an object for an Android Array Adapter

Tags: java, android

Im using an array adapter with a list view as follows:

```
ArrayList<Store> allStores = dm.getAll(Store.class);

ArrayAdapter<Store> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Store>(context,R.layout.listview_layout,   R.id.textView1, allStores);

ListView mylist = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewFromDb);
mylist.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The array that I pass into the listview is an array of objects. At the minute the list prints out all of the attributes of the object is it possible to just print the first attribute of the object so "name". Please help

Answer (score 0):

Extend the ArrayAdapter and override the getView method, using the position argument to access the element in the array.  Here is an example from [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#arrayAdapter):

The following example doesn't recycle views, so keep that in mind as it will affect performance (a great deal on some devices).

```
package de.vogella.android.listactivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  private final Context context;
  private final String[] values;

  public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    textView.setText(values[position]);
    // Change the icon for Windows and iPhone
    String s = values[position];
    if (s.startsWith("iPhone")) {
      imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no);
    } else {
      imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
    }

    return rowView;
  }
}
```